# How to serve a static JSONP file from the server?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I am trying to put a static jsonp file (jsonp-test.php) in the server but I'm not able to read it. This is what I have:

```
mycallback[
  {"key":"1","val":"test1"},
  {"key":"2","val":"test2"}
]
```

And this is how I'm trying to read it:

```
var url = "http://www.remote-server/jsonp-test.php?callback=mycallback";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  alert(data.toSource());
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: jsonp-test.php doesn't sound like a static file. Is `mycallback` hard coded somewhere, or does the script use the `callback` query parameter to set this? Will this continue to be a PHP script or are you planning to convert it to a static file?

Comment: @MichaelGeary `mycallback` is hard-coded inside jsonp-test.php. Currently there is no dynamic information inside jsonp-test.php.

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of things...  When you say "I am not able to read it", can you verify that you are actually requesting the JSONP from the correct address?  For instance, can you open the URL

```
http://www.remote-server/jsonp-test.php?callback=mycallback
```

in a browser tab and see the JSONP.  If so, then a secondary problem I think you have the format of your JSONP is incorrect.  mycallback is actually the name of a function that gets called, so the content of your JSON should be enclosed in parens with a semi, like below

```
mycallback(
  [
  {"key":"1","val":"test1"},
  {"key":"2","val":"test2"}
  ]
);
```

Comment: Yes I am able to open the URL in the browser. I also made changes to the JSONP like you suggested but I still cannot read it from the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

First, as Bradley explained, fix the syntax of the JSONP file - it needs those parentheses. That's because the file needs to be valid JavaScript code. JSONP is just a convention for using a JavaScript function call to load JSON data from a script file.

If the file will remain static - in particular if the name of the `mycallback` function is hard coded - then you should probably just treat it as a script file that calls a global function, because that's what it really is. Define a global function named `mycallback`, and use `$.getScript()` to load your static JSONP/JavaScript file:

```
window.mycallback = function( data ) {
    alert( data.toSource() );
};

$.getScript( 'http://www.remote-server/jsonp-test.php' );
```

Note that you don't need the `?callback=mycallback` for a static file either.